# Python Beautifulsoup get text based from first few lines in the string of jsonized html code

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I have the following json file to traverse:

```
[
{"title":"HB00001", "history":"<div class=\"fetched-data\"><table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"auto\"><tbody><tr><td colspan=\"3\">House Bill\/Resolution NO. <b>HB00001<\/b><\/td><\/tr><tr><td colspan=\"3\">FULL TITLE : AN ACT REQUIRING PRIVATE CONTRACTORS TO WHOM PROVINCIAL, CITY AND MUNICIPAL PUBLIC WORKS PROJECTS HAVE BEEN AWARDED UNDER CONTRACT TO HIRE NOT MORE THAN 30 PER CENT OF THE UNEMPLOYED RESIDENTS OF THEPROVINCE, CITY OR MUNICIPALITY IN WHICH THE PROJECT OR PROJECTS ARE TO BE UNDERTAKEN IN THEIR WORK FORCE, AND PENALIZING THOSE WHO FAIL TO DO SO<\/td><\/tr><tr><td colspan=\"3\">PRINCIPAL AUTHOR\/S : <b>PUYAT-REYES, MA. CONSUELO<\/b><\/td><\/tr><tr><td colspan=\"3\">DATE FILED : 1987-07-22<\/td><\/tr><tr><td colspan=\"3\">SIGNIFICANCE: NATIONAL<\/td><\/tr><tr><td colspan=\"3\">CO-AUTHORS : <\/td><\/tr><tr><td width=\"33%\">1. Bagatsing<\/td><\/tr><tr><td colspan=\"3\">ADMINISTRATION BILL? No<\/td><\/tr><tr><td colspan=\"3\">URGENT BILL? No<\/td><\/tr><tr><td colspan=\"3\">COMMITTEE ACTION: SUBSTITUTE D BY HB 3283 (CR 36)-RA0668 5.<\/td><\/tr><tr><td colspan=\"3\"><b>ACTIONS TAKEN BY THE COMMITTEE ON RULES<\/b><\/td><\/tr><tr><td colspan=\"3\">REFERRAL TO THE COMMITTEE ON PUBLIC WORKS AND HIGHWAYS ON 1987-07-28<\/td><\/tr><\/tbody><\/table><\/div>"}
```

]

I am able to open it python through the following code:

```
f = open('test2.json')
y = json.load(f)

for data in y:
    title = data["title"]
    wd = data["history"]
    
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(wd, 'lxml')
```

For the full title ( the td with text "FULL TITLE: " in the first twelve lines ), I am able to get it using the code below.

```
full_title = soup.find('td', text=re.compile('FULL TITLE :')).get_text()
```

How come for the principal author (td with text "PRINCIPAL AUTHOR" in the first fifteen lines) code below, I don't get anything:

```
principal_author = soup.find_all('td', text=re.compile("PRINCIPAL AUTHOR"))
print (principal_author)
```

I've also tried

```
principal_author = soup.find('td', text=re.compile("PRINCIPAL AUTHOR"))
```

How do I get the text for this?

Answer (score 1):

First thing, don't import bs4 in the loop. It's going to run that line after each iteration.

You are running into issues because of encode/decoding of the html. Notice the `<\/td>` in the html. Beautifulsoup is then not parsing it correctly. This is what you get if you just do `.find('td').text`

```
soup.find('td').text
Out[35]: 'House Bill\\/Resolution NO. HB00001<\\/b><\\/td><\\/tr>FULL TITLE : AN ACT REQUIRING PRIVATE CONTRACTORS TO WHOM PROVINCIAL, CITY AND MUNICIPAL PUBLIC WORKS PROJECTS HAVE BEEN AWARDED UNDER CONTRACT TO HIRE NOT MORE THAN 30 PER CENT OF THE UNEMPLOYED RESIDENTS OF THEPROVINCE, CITY OR MUNICIPALITY IN WHICH THE PROJECT OR PROJECTS ARE TO BE UNDERTAKEN IN THEIR WORK FORCE, AND PENALIZING THOSE WHO FAIL TO DO SO<\\/td><\\/tr>PRINCIPAL AUTHOR\\/S : PUYAT-REYES, MA. CONSUELO<\\/b><\\/td><\\/tr>DATE FILED : 1987-07-22<\\/td><\\/tr>SIGNIFICANCE: NATIONAL<\\/td><\\/tr>CO-AUTHORS : <\\/td><\\/tr>1. Bagatsing<\\/td><\\/tr>ADMINISTRATION BILL? No<\\/td><\\/tr>URGENT BILL? No<\\/td><\\/tr>COMMITTEE ACTION: SUBSTITUTE D BY HB 3283 (CR 36)-RA0668 5.<\\/td><\\/tr>ACTIONS TAKEN BY THE COMMITTEE ON RULES<\\/b><\\/td><\\/tr>REFERRAL TO THE COMMITTEE ON PUBLIC WORKS AND HIGHWAYS ON 1987-07-28<\\/td><\\/tr><\\/tbody><\\/table><\\/div>'
```

So need to fix those escapes.

Then we can get those parts. It is odd that it doesn't work the same as the `'FULL TITLE :'`, as I dodn't see why it's returning None. But you could simply do a list comprehension to find those tags then:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

y = [
{"title":"HB00001", "history":"<div class=\"fetched-data\"><table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"auto\"><tbody><tr><td colspan=\"3\">House Bill\/Resolution NO. <b>HB00001<\/b><\/td><\/tr><tr><td colspan=\"3\">FULL TITLE : AN ACT REQUIRING PRIVATE CONTRACTORS TO WHOM PROVINCIAL, CITY AND MUNICIPAL PUBLIC WORKS PROJECTS HAVE BEEN AWARDED UNDER CONTRACT TO HIRE NOT MORE THAN 30 PER CENT OF THE UNEMPLOYED RESIDENTS OF THEPROVINCE, CITY OR MUNICIPALITY IN WHICH THE PROJECT OR PROJECTS ARE TO BE UNDERTAKEN IN THEIR WORK FORCE, AND PENALIZING THOSE WHO FAIL TO DO SO<\/td><\/tr><tr><td colspan=\"3\">PRINCIPAL AUTHOR\/S : <b>PUYAT-REYES, MA. CONSUELO<\/b><\/td><\/tr><tr><td colspan=\"3\">DATE FILED : 1987-07-22<\/td><\/tr><tr><td colspan=\"3\">SIGNIFICANCE: NATIONAL<\/td><\/tr><tr><td colspan=\"3\">CO-AUTHORS : <\/td><\/tr><tr><td width=\"33%\">1. Bagatsing<\/td><\/tr><tr><td colspan=\"3\">ADMINISTRATION BILL? No<\/td><\/tr><tr><td colspan=\"3\">URGENT BILL? No<\/td><\/tr><tr><td colspan=\"3\">COMMITTEE ACTION: SUBSTITUTE D BY HB 3283 (CR 36)-RA0668 5.<\/td><\/tr><tr><td colspan=\"3\"><b>ACTIONS TAKEN BY THE COMMITTEE ON RULES<\/b><\/td><\/tr><tr><td colspan=\"3\">REFERRAL TO THE COMMITTEE ON PUBLIC WORKS AND HIGHWAYS ON 1987-07-28<\/td><\/tr><\/tbody><\/table><\/div>"}]

for data in y:
    title = data["title"]
    wd = data["history"]

    wd = wd.replace('\\',"")
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(wd, 'lxml')
    full_title = soup.find('td', text=re.compile('FULL TITLE :')).get_text()
    principal_author = [x.text for x in soup.find_all('td') if 'PRINCIPAL AUTHOR' in x.text]
```

**Output:**

```
print(full_title)
FULL TITLE : AN ACT REQUIRING PRIVATE CONTRACTORS TO WHOM PROVINCIAL, CITY AND MUNICIPAL PUBLIC WORKS PROJECTS HAVE BEEN AWARDED UNDER CONTRACT TO HIRE NOT MORE THAN 30 PER CENT OF THE UNEMPLOYED RESIDENTS OF THEPROVINCE, CITY OR MUNICIPALITY IN WHICH THE PROJECT OR PROJECTS ARE TO BE UNDERTAKEN IN THEIR WORK FORCE, AND PENALIZING THOSE WHO FAIL TO DO SO

print(principal_author)
['PRINCIPAL AUTHOR/S : PUYAT-REYES, MA. CONSUELO']
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this! I was suspecting that also with my json file since I escaped special characters to make it a valid json file. I have similar fields that I need to iterate, can I add regex here: [x.text for x in soup.find_all('td') if 'PRINCIPAL AUTHOR' in x.text]. And also, I checked the type of principal_author, it seems it a list. My follow up question though is how to make ['PRINCIPAL AUTHOR/S : PUYAT-REYES, MA. CONSUELO'] it to: PRINCIPAL AUTHOR/S : PUYAT-REYES, MA. CONSUELO. Though, this will be okay since I can find replace "['" and "']" in my result.